# Hive UDF dependency broken?

Tags: maven, hadoop, hive

I'm trying to include hive-exec jar as a dependency to my project so that I can create custom UDFs.
The maven artifact http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.hive/hive-exec/0.8.1 has a dependency on 
http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.hive/hive-metastore/0.8.1 which in turn depends on jd2-api version 2.3-ec. But http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/javax.jdo/jdo2-api does not have 2.3-ec.

How can I get past this ?

Comment: hive-exec : 0.9.0 also has this bug ... :(